# File Explorer shell extensions editor?

Tags: windows, windows-8, shell-extensions, windows-explorer

I have a bunch of shell extensions which show up from the right mouse click. I would like to delete the ones I never use. Is there a tool which can do this? I know they can be removed from the registry but I couldn't find some of them in the registry and I prefer to use a tool which can safely remove them. (using Windows 8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Autoruns for Windows v11.42](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) from the Sysinternals Suite.

Disable the Explorer extension:

[image: Explorer extension disable]

Comment: Updated link to Autoruns: [Autoruns for Windows v14.06](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns). Autoruns did the job quite well for me just minutes ago. (It is too early to conclude anything about potential unintended consequences, though.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ccleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) Like this: Tools > Startup > Context Menu
[image]

Or use [Shell Menu View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) by NirSoft.

Comment: ShellMenuNew is only for the *New* items menu. ShellExView and ShellMenuView would be better.